# Firefox keep some bookmarks on local machine only?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I want to bookmark some URLs on my filesystem that won't work on my other machines but I still want to use account synchronizing for the http(s) URLs. Is it possible to create local bookmarks in Firefox that won't get synchronized?

Comment: "Passwords will stop syncing in Firefox for Android once the master password has been set." https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-sync-troubleshooting-and-tips

Comment: You misunderstood my question, I still want to automatically sync *some* bookmarks, like `https://` bookmarks but not others, like `file:/...` bookmarks.

Comment: Sorry, how about a Firefox add-on? https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/webext-private-bookmarks/

Comment: In Windows, create a personal/private account keeping it password protected.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that you can create a local bookmark within Firefox.

However, you can drag the URL from the address bar and drop it into the folder where you want to keep them. This creates a shortcut in the folder. Double click the shortcut will launch the URL in the default browser.

Here is the official documentation about this feature: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/create-desktop-shortcut-website